# Today is an important day for us

Tags: riddle, word, affix-riddle

- our prefix makes us taller... sometimes.
- our infix is something you are, starting from today.
- our suffix is one of our elements.

> Who are we and why is today (December 7, 2020) such an important day for us?

Hint 1

> The suffix clue is related to [science](/questions/tagged/science).

Hint 2

> The grammar in the infix part is a bit stretched, read it as "You are ...., starting from today!"

Hint 3

> The prefix clue is related to [computer-science](/questions/tagged/computer-science) but a lot of people use it daily.

Comment: Just to throw this out there, are we dealing with acronyms or abbreviations?

Comment: @MacGyver88 both the prefix and the suffix are abbreviations, the whole answer is not. You may think this makes the solution harder to guess but I think the abbreviation for the prefix is more known that the actual word (:

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've got it at last! You are:

> **TABLES** - and 7 December 2020 is a significant day for 'you' because as of this date *[support for **table syntax** was enabled across the whole of the Stack Exchange network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support)*!

*our prefix makes us taller... sometimes.*

> Using the **TAB** key on a computer keyboard can change the size of a table row or column in programs like MS Word, which sometimes affects the table's height.

*our infix is something you are, starting from today.*

> *Starting from 'today'* (07-Dec-2020), you are **ABLE** to use tables in your posts on Stack Exchange sites like Puzzling.

*our suffix is one of our elements.*

> **Es** is the chemical symbol for Einsteinium, one of the *elements* in the Periodic *Table*!

Put it all together with overlap:

> **TAB** + **ABLE** + **ES** = **TABLES**!

Comment: well done, this is the intended answer!

Comment: Gosh, that prefix seems like a bit of a stretch, otherwise wonderful!

Answer (score 3):

Could be

> **AIRBNB**

our prefix makes us taller... sometimes.

> **AI** - used to improve programming, can work well if used the correct way

our infix is something you are, starting from today.

> **IRB** - I Are Back, texted after BRB (Be Right Back) or
>  **IRB** - Investor Revenue Base ?, or **IR** - Income Resource ? (stretch)

our suffix is one of our elements.

> **BNB** - Bed & Breakfast, one of the services offered by Airbnb

Who are we and why is today such an important day for us?

> Monday, Dec 7th, Airbnb was headlined as launching their IPO into the NYSE later in the week, getting prospective investors ready to buy their stock.
>  (Probably incorrect because it makes more sense to have Wednesday, Dec 9th be their important day due to their IPO being lauched at that time.)

Comment: Not the intended answer, sorry. The infix does not fit well, but here is a +1 anyway.

Answer (score 2):

My guess:

> [Pearl Harbor Remembrance Day](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=pearl+harbor+date) *(takes place at December 7th, that's today)*

*our prefix makes us taller... sometimes.*

> Owning a pearl makes use feel taller, as in richer.

*our infix is something you are, starting from today.*

> Wow, will I really be remembered for answering this puzzle?

*our suffix is one of our elements.*

> Yep, that's "day".

*Who are we and why is today such an important day for us?*

> We are human, and today is special because today is when a big part of history was made.

Comment: That's completely unrelated with the intended answer but... nice try, have a +1.